# Angular Github pages deploy change default start file

Tags: angular, github, deployment, github-pages

I have an Angular application and I wanted to publish it on github pages. I followed this page:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-github-pages
and everything went great. But if I go to page with project, I see Angular information about project, how to build, test etc. I have to go to nick.github.io/projectName/index.html to see my project. Can I somehow make this that if I go to project page, I see my page, without needing to go to index.html file manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there was no problem at all, Github pages just needed some time to properly upload files and set them. After few minutes I did not have manualy go to index.html, just insert my page and it automatically read index.html.